# Standard errors for non-linear least squares in R

Tags: r, standard-error, nonlinear, nls

I have a question on standard errors for non-linear least squares in R. With the built-in function NLS and a hand-made function I get different SE and I don't understand why. I will try to expose below a simpler and replicable example of my original problem.

I want to estimate the mean $\mu$ and the standard deviation $\sigma$ of a normal cumulative distribution function.

Let's simulate the data for this example in R:

```
set.seed(12)
mu <- 5
sigma <- 2
x <- runif(100, min = 0, max = 10)
y <- pnorm(x + rnorm(1), mu, sigma)
df <- data.frame(y,var1)
```

I assume a true value for $\mu$ of 5 and 2 for $\sigma$. I add a normal noise to y which is a cdf of x.

I first fit a non-linear least squares with the built-in function NLS:

```
res1 <- nls(y ~ pnorm(x, mean = mu, sd = sigma), 
            data = df, start = c(mu = 1,sigma = 1), algorithm = "port")
summary(res1)
```

I get the following result that I was expected

```
Formula: y ~ pnorm(x, mean = mu, sd = sigma)

Parameters:
                    Estimate             Std. Error            t value
mu    5.04268491217399539295 0.00000000000000003347 150682292747528064
sigma 2.00000000000000000000 0.00000000000000004567  43795073347627272
                 Pr(>|t|)    
mu    <0.0000000000000002 ***
sigma <0.0000000000000002 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.00000000000000003995 on 98 degrees of freedom

Algorithm "port", convergence message: X-convergence (3)
```

Secondly, I tried my own LS estimation

```
f <- function(par){
  mu = par[1]
  sigma = par[2]
  temp <- pnorm(df$x, mean = mu, sd = sigma)
  sum1 <- sum((df$y-temp)^2)
  return(sum1)
}

res2 <- optim(c(1,1),f,method = "L-BFGS-B",
              lower=c(0,0), upper = c(100,100), hessian = TRUE)
print(res2)
```

I get similar result for the coefficients:

```
$par
[1] 5.042685 1.999999

$value
[1] 0.000000000001761186

$counts
function gradient 
      20       20 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"

$hessian
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  2.8835336 -0.2273554
[2,] -0.2273554  1.5485147
```

But when I compute the Standard Errors, I don't get the same result with the NLS:

```
sqrt(diag(res2$hessian))
[1] 1.698097 1.244393
```

Does someone know why ?

Thank you !

Alexis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am almost certain that you are running into the same problem as [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205419/non-linear-least-squares-standard-error-calculation-in-r).

The thing is that `optim` is agnostic of any kind of least squares modeling, so you just get the *pure* hessian out. The std error has been scaled in `nls`.